# How to extract different elements of a list at the same time

Tags: r

I have a function where its argument is a list. This argument is run for different values.  My original function is very difficult. Hence, I posted an example which similar to part of my function.

**The example here is multiplication (just to show the idea). I think `for` cannot work here, since, `for` loop takes element by element, while I need to take two different elements of a list at the same time**

### All the idea is,

how to make this part of the code `xxx <- myfun(z[[1]][k,j],z[[2]][k,i]))` works for arbirtary number of elements, instead of doing it manually.
For example, if I have `3` matrices, then, I would write the code as this:
`xxx <- myfun(z[[1]][k,j],z[[2]][k,i], z[[3]][k,j])`. How to make this automatically not manually.

For example, `z` is a list of matrices. I would like to run my function for specific values of these matrices. That is, each time I would like my function to select specific elements of my matrices. Here is my code:

```
x <- c(0,1,2,
       0,0,1,
       0,0,0)
x <- matrix(x,3,3)

y <- c(0,2,3,
       0,0,1,
       0,0,0)
y <- matrix(y,3,3)
z <- list(x,y)



     myfun <- function(f=list()){
  s <- length(f)
  xy <- list()
  for(i in 1:s){
    xy[[i]] <- 2*f[[i]]

  }
  xy
}
```

### Here is my try.

### Please note that,

here, I would like the function to takes specific values from the matrices `x` and `y` and plug them into a list in my function. I would like to make it works for an arbitrary number of elements of a list. That is, sometimes, I have `3` matrices or `4`. Hence, the number of matrices is not fixed.

## I try the following and works just fine, however, how to make it works for any number of the elements.

```
 xxx <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
for(k in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:3){
    xxx[[i]] <- myfun(f=list(z[[1]][1,2],z[[2]][1,2]))
  }
}
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: I am android developer with java background dont want you misguided with coding so here's an example which I think will help you, good luck https://codeforwin.org/2015/07/c-program-to-multiply-two-matrices.html

Comment: Could you post an example of the output? I am not sure what you intend to perform on the matrices?

Comment: @missuse I updated my question.

Comment: `myfun(z[[1]][1,2])` doesn't return anything (well, it does return ` NULL`  ).  `myfun(z[[1]][1,2],z[[2]][1,2])` returns an "unused argument" error. Something is clearly missing here. You should first try to get your function to work the way you intend it to work.

Comment: I would like to help but this is all very unclear

Comment: @Seymour thanks for your great comment. All the idea is how can I make this `xxx <- myfun(z[[1]][k,j],z[[2]][k,i], z[[3]][k,j])` works for arbirtary number of length, automatically.

Comment: @JulienNavarre thanks for your comment. I would like to make it general, not manually.

Comment: I would say that you should use the `...` when defining function number so it can take an arbitrary number of arguments

Comment: @Seymour Is that what do you mean `myfun(f=list(...))`. The idea is how to select two or three different values of the list at the same time.

Comment: I am just saying in general that maybe you should check out how to use the constructe `myfun <- function(...)` because maybe can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the following bit correctly

> All the idea is how can I make this `xxx <- myfun(z[[1]][k,j],z[[2]][k,i], z[[3]][k,j])` works for arbirtary number of length, automatically

this should be what you are looking for:

```
xxx <- myfun(f=lapply(z, function(x){x[k,j]}))
```

For k=1 and j=2

```
xxx <- myfun(f=lapply(z, function(x){x[1,2]}))
```

returns the same as the example you provided.

Comment: Do i need to have like this:`for (k in 1:3) { for (i in 1:3){ xxx <- myfun(list(lapply(z, function(x){x[k,j]}),
                  lapply(z, function(x){x[k,j]})))}}`

Comment: I edited my answer, please try the newly edited code.